# Install Angular CLI Offline trys to connect

Tags: npm, angular-cli, offline-caching

I am attempting to install Angular CLI in an offline environment using cache. The approach I am using is
1.  copy the npm-cache folder from %appdata% folder ( from my online machine which has Angular already installed)
2. Place it in my offline machine.
3. Run this command to install angular cli from cache:

```
npm i @angular/cli -g --cache MY_CACHE_FOLDER --cache-min 999999999 --no-shrinkwrap
```

I receive the following error:

FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.22.35:443

My question is, why is npm trying to look online, when I specified to use cache?